# Dropzone.js v5 not showing files from server: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm building a single image upload form using the most recent [Dropzone.js](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone) v5.1. I need to show files that are already stored in my server so I followed the [official tutorial](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server) in the repo wiki. My code  looks like this:

```
Dropzone.options.mainMediaForm = {
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 2,
    maxFiles: 1,
    thumbnailHeight: null,
    thumbnailWidth: null,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            if (this.files.length > 1) {
                this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
        this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
            if (file.width != imageWidth || file.height != imageHeight) {
                file.rejectDimensions()
            }
            else {
                file.acceptDimensions();
            }
        });
        // Start of tutorial code //
        var mockFile = { name: "Filename", size: 12345 };
        this.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
        this.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "url/image.jpg");
        this.emit("complete", mockFile);
        // End of tutorial code //
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        file.acceptDimensions = done;
        file.rejectDimensions = function() { done("Invalid dimension."); };
    }
};
```

Everything works just fine except the tutorial code applied, which logs an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
at Dropzone.addedfile (dropzone.js:296)
at Dropzone.Emitter.emit (dropzone.js:58)
at Dropzone.init (edit:516)
at Dropzone.init (dropzone.js:721)
at new Dropzone (dropzone.js:506)
at Function.Dropzone.discover (dropzone.js:1596)
at Dropzone._autoDiscoverFunction (dropzone.js:2046)
at HTMLDocument.init (dropzone.js:2015)
```

Here is the HTML, quite standard:

```
<!-- Main media form -->
<form id="main-media-form" action="action/url" class="dropzone">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

I've already tried some other answers I found here in SO, but none of them worked, getting always the same error. At this point I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or the tutorial is outdated.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue.
Now fixed in version **5.1.1**!

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and i solve it by using a previous version of dropzone , its a problem with v 5